# Button onChange is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the  content with javascript. The change is called with an onClick event in the button.

When I click on the button `ok2017` nothing is happening.

Does someone know what is wrong?

**Edit 1:**

Here is the code as a runnable snippet

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeDivContent() {
    document.getElementById('graphcon').innerHTML = '<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>';
  }
</script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="ok2017" id="ok2017" onClick="changeDivContent()"> 2017
  </label>
</div>


<div id="graphcon" class="graphcon"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the element with an ID of graphcon? To confirm whether the function is being called but not doing what you expect, try add a console.log("working"); into `changeDivContent()`

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? Where is the element which has the ID of `graphcon`, also you don't need to get the `innerHTML` to `innerHTML='';` since you will be overwriting/replacing the `innerHTML` with the canvas tag.

Comment: Logically, why bother with `.innerHTML = '';` if the next line overwrites it anyway? Also, your code works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/obmynjvp/

Comment: See edit 1 in my first post for the <div>

Comment: .innerHTML = ''; is to clear the previous data. I am using multiple buttons

Comment: Do you see any errors in broswer's console? The code posted does look right to me.

Comment: ".innerHTML = ''; is to clear the previous data" -- what is the "previous data" here? What do you mean by "nothing is happening"?

Comment: I believe your code works, but adding that canvas in the `graphcon` div doesn't mean that anything will be drawn on that canvas. If you try some _text_ instead of a _canvas_, you will see that it ends up in that div.

Comment: @MariosHadjimichael even if there is no content in the canvas, the canvas will occupy some space in page, which is definitely not "nothing is happening"

Comment: @shaochuancs that depends... If you have the `graphcon` as the last element, you wouldn't be able to tell if there is a blank canvas.

Comment: I have replaced `<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>` with `<p>test</p>` and it is still the same. With nothing is happening I mean that I cant see `<p>test</p>`

Comment: @John can you make a jsfiddle or codepen that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @John look at the answer posted, your code works. Run the the code, then right click the area below the button and select inspect. You'll see the devtools popup and the source code in a window. The highlighted element should be `#myChart`.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle with my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/cgxaezq4/

Comment: I tried to inspect the area. `<div id="graphcon" class="graphcon"></div>` is still empty

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question, not only on jsFiddle. And in that code you run `document.getElementById("myChart")` before the element with that ID is created.

Comment: *".innerHTML = ''; is to clear the previous data."* - That's not necessary. Assigning a new value automatically overwrites the previous data.

Comment: @j08691 I added the most important part of my code. I think the problem is in that part I posted. On jsfiddle I added my full code to show that it is not working

Comment: @nnnnnn I deleted that part from my first post

Comment: And I explained that you need to include a [mcve] **in your question** and not force people to visit another site to see the problem. I also noted that you get the contents of an element before it even exists.

Comment: @j08691 I updated that in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cgxaezq4/1/ the result is still the same. Should I add the #myChart in my question?

Comment: @j08691 Now you see why I posted that lame answer?

Answer (score 0):

Actually canvas is being added to your `graphcon` div.You are executing script before adding `canvas` to DOM. place your script code inside `changeDivContent`()` function after adding canvas. it works.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
            
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="ok2017" id="ok2017" onClick="changeDivContent()"> 2017
  </label>
</div>

<div id="graphcon" class="graphcon"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeDivContent() {
   document.getElementById('graphcon').innerHTML = 'sdfsdfsdfsdf';
    document.getElementById('graphcon').innerHTML = '<canvas id="myChart">asd</canvas>';
     var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
  data: {
   labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Label 1",
     data: [500, 400, 200, 300, 1000, 3000, 3000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
     backgroundColor: ['rgba(2, 255, 109, 0.5)'],
     borderColor: ['rgba(2,255,109,1)'],
     borderWidth: 1
    }, {
     label: "Label 2",
     data: [500, 400, 200, 300, 1000, 3000, 3000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
     backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'],
     borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
     borderWidth: 1
        }]
   },
   options: {
     scales: {
     yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
       beginAtZero:true
      }
     }]
    }
   }
  });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It is working in the snippet but on my site it is not working. I figured out that there is a problem with the `<input type>`. The onchange is not running when the input type = `radio`. When I change that to `button` the script is working. Do you know why I am having that problem?